Missing antialiasing on Filling
They seem to forget add antialiasing on Filling.
When style is transparent we can see a rough boundary.
When style is not transparent the boundary is overlaid with the curve of plotting function on which the antialiasing is used, so no rough boundary is visible.
Is this the same with newer versions of Mathematica?
$Version
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.05, Sin[x] + 0.06, 
  Sin[x] + 0.11}, {x, Pi/2 - 0.5, Pi/2 + 0.5}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}, 3 -> {{4}, Red}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Transparent, Transparent}, 
 Background -> Green]


"13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"



Same with V 13.3.0 and Mac OS - also with white Background and increased PlotPoints

The same behaviour is observed in "14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)", but you can just simply manually enable Antialiasing for fillings.
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.05, Sin[x] + 0.06, Sin[x] + 0.11}, {x, 
  Pi/2 - 0.5, Pi/2 + 0.5}, PlotStyle -> None,
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Style[Red, Antialiasing -> True]}, 
             3 -> {{4}, Style[Red, Antialiasing -> True]}}]


To get it working also in 13.3, you can put the Antialiasing in FillingStyle:
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.05, Sin[x] + 0.06, Sin[x] + 0.11}, {x, 
  Pi/2 - 0.5, Pi/2 + 0.5}, PlotStyle -> None, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 3 -> {4}}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Red, Antialiasing -> True]]

or, as you've figured it out yourself in the comments, wrap the whole thing with Style:
Style[Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] + 0.05, Sin[x] + 0.06, Sin[x] + 0.11}, {x, 
   Pi/2 - 0.5, Pi/2 + 0.5}, PlotStyle -> None, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Red}, 3 -> {{4}, Red}}], 
 Antialiasing -> True]


Unfortunately it does not work with my version. Anyway (+1), as it may help others that have your version.

It works with 14.0, but not with 13.3

@Domen But it works if I wrap the whole plot in Style like Style[Plot[ ...], Antialiasing -> True]. Add this to your answer and I will accept it. Anyway it is a bug to me - no relevant reason to not apply antialiasing on fillings.

@Domen It also works on version 13 with Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Red, Antialiasing -> True]}} instead of using style.
